# What does this internal NullPointException from AspectJ API mean?

Tags: aspectj

I wrote some code to weave binary codes using ajc API. Here it is:

```
// assemble compile options
String[] args = {
        "-1.7",
        "-showWeaveInfo",
        "-encoding", "UTF-8",
        "-inpath", inpath,
        "-d", output.getOutFile().getAbsolutePath(),
        "-bootclasspath", bootpath};

// run compile
MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
new Main().run(args, handler);
```

My purpose is to weave all project binary codes together. And I used it in Gradle for my Android projects.
But it throws an NPE within:

```
---- AspectJ Properties ---
AspectJ Compiler 1.8.7 built on Wednesday Sep 9, 2015 at 21:19:30 GMT
---- Dump Properties ---
Dump file: ajcore.20151022.173902.134.txt
Dump reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
Dump on exception: true
Dump at exit condition: abort
---- Exception Information ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.aspectj.weaver.AbstractReferenceTypeDelegate.getFormalTypeParametersFromOuterClass(AbstractReferenceTypeDelegate.java:111)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:772)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getSuperclass(BcelObjectType.java:231)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getSuperclass(ReferenceType.java:987)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveParentsFor(BcelWeaver.java:1300)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1119)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.weaveQueuedEntries(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:514)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterCompiling(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:375)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$afterReturning$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$2$f9cc9ca0(CompilerAdapter.aj:78)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:471)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1036)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:272)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:114)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
at com.meituan.android.aspectj.AspectJTransform.transform(AspectJTransform.java:105)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I did some troubleshooting, and I think this is where it went wrong in `BcelObjectType.getOuterClass()`:

```
// try finding outer class name by assuming standard class name mangling convention of javac for this class
int lastDollar = className.lastIndexOf('$');
if (lastDollar == -1) {
    // Is this class damaged/obfuscated? Why did we think it was nested but couldn't find the parent using
    // the attributes above. For now just ignore it... I wonder when ignoring this will come back to bite!
    return null;
}
```

The most interesting thing is the build code does work in my demo but fails in a complicated project(one with a little bit more library dependencies). Since I'm not a AspectJ developer, I don't know what's going on here at all. So is there anybody who can tell me what this exception means? is there any typical mistake that people will make when this exception happens?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and raised bug [482945](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482945) for it.

In my case it is caused by a specific inner class that has been obfuscated to the point where the outer class is no longer in the name of the inner class (outer$inner). Still, for some reason, the underlying BCEL code determines it is an inner class and tries to determine the outer class. Other similarly obfuscated classes don't give the same error.

When you run your project on the command line, the class that is the cause is printed out. For some reason it is not in the ajcore file.

My workaround has been to exclude the specific class from weaving in my aop.xml file, as I know it is not affected by my aspects:

```
<weaver options="-nowarn -Xlint:ignore">
  <exclude within="com.tibco.xml.parsers.xmlfactories.b"/>
</weaver>
```

Note that it is also clear why you encounter the issue only in a complicated project. The class that causes this is very likely in an additional library that is only included in the complicated project.